# Bootstrap 3 col-xs columns inside a container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

It seems to me that bootstrap 3 has a flaw in that is it no possible to properly use `.col-xs-*` columns inside a container that isn't a fluid container.

To demonstrate what I mean check out this jsfiddle and downside the view to `xs` size (below 768px).

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38322/

**DEMO**

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

.container {
  background: grey;  
}
  .col-md-3 {
   border-left: 1px solid blue;
  }
p {
     background: whitesmoke;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam eos voluptas repellat, culpa debitis minus odio officia, magni fugiat voluptatem soluta laudantium quam, accusamus quisquam, a aspernatur impedit veniam dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam eos voluptas repellat, culpa debitis minus odio officia, magni fugiat voluptatem soluta laudantium quam, accusamus quisquam, a aspernatur impedit veniam dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam eos voluptas repellat, culpa debitis minus odio officia, magni fugiat voluptatem soluta laudantium quam, accusamus quisquam, a aspernatur impedit veniam dolor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam eos voluptas repellat, culpa debitis minus odio officia, magni fugiat voluptatem soluta laudantium quam, accusamus quisquam, a aspernatur impedit veniam dolor.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see how the grid is doubled in between elements adding up to a gutter of 30px while having a gutter between the elements and the container of 15px on the left and right sides.

The 30px is normal and I understand this happens because both paddings are added up.

But for example on the `lg` scale, the bootstrap container is given a `max-width` of `1170px`. This is done through a media query for a window size of `1200px` and wider. After that the max-width is adjusted again to `970px` for the container.

This effectively means your container will always have `30px` of room left (1200 - 1170). After that the container downscales again with the `970` `max-width` value.

This concept is kind of 'faking' a gutter that is not there, but this does not work when you can no longer set a `max-width` on the container and the container has a `100%` width like on the mobile scale.

I hope it is clear what I mean. This makes me wonder if `col-xs-*` columns were ever meant to be used inside a container that is not a fluid-container.

What is the best way to deal with this if I would want for example two `col-xs-6` columns inside a container and have evenly spaced gutters? Even spacing between:

- the container and the first column
- the first column and the second column
- the second column and the container

Comment: Please post your code also here on SO. External sites like jsfiddle could disappear without prior notice

Comment: Maybe it is not the nicest way, but you can wrap your inner elements into additional `col-xs-` class. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38329/